# Cant get value from switch button to the second activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I made a switch button for something like "dark mode",basically it should change the app color, and it does, but only in the first activity, then, when i try to pass the boolean value to the 2nd activity it doesn't change the color of anything.

Main activity :

```
        public void nightview(View view) {
    Intent intent4 = new Intent(this, DisplayResultActivit.class);
    Switch sw1 = findViewById(R.id.nightview);
    boolean switchstate = sw1.isChecked();
    intent4.putExtra("state", switchstate);
    if (switchstate) {
        //nightview
        View lay = findViewById(R.id.layout); 
        ...
```

2nd activity :

```
    boolean state = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("state");
        if (state) {
            //nightview
            View lay2 = findViewById(R.id.layout2);
            lay2.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            TextView tv1 = findViewById(R.id.textView);
            tv1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        } else {
            //dayview
            View lay2 = findViewById(R.id.layout2);
            lay2.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            TextView tv1 = findViewById(R.id.textView);
            tv1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
```

Comment: Can we see the startactivity intent, please?

Comment: @CarlosLópezMarí well it's calculator so it depends on what i'll click, in the switch button method i don't have the startactivity intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a class AppPreference like this:-

```
public class AppPrefrences {

    private static SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    private static SharedPreferences.Editor mPrefsEditor;

    public static boolean getSwitchValue(Context ctx) {
        mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        return mPrefs.getBoolean("switch", false);
    }

    public static void setSwitchValue(Context ctx, Boolean value) {
        mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        mPrefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
        mPrefsEditor.putBoolean("switch", value);
        mPrefsEditor.commit();
    }
}
```

and set values from all the activities like this:- 
to set switch value in preference:-

```
setSwitchValue(MainActivity.this, true);
```

to get switch value in all activites:-

```
getSwitchValue(MainActvity2.class);
```

Comment: Changed, but it still only shows the day mode, even if i change it to night mode, like it doesn't get the value from the 1st activity.

Comment: Now it works, but the problem is i don't want this method to startactivity, i dont want it to go to the second activity, what can i do?

Comment: what you want to do ? according to your question i have suggest you what i know.

Comment: When i write the startacivity it goes to 2nd activity, and i want it to stay on the 1st activity but just pass the value to the 2nd activity.

Comment: you can save your switch value in shared preference to use everywhere in app.

Comment: Well, i'm quite a noob and i actually dont understand the code, what should i do with it, just copy&paste or what? Sorry xd

Comment: you can copy app preference class and use these 2 methods across the app to set value or get value.

Comment: I did it but when i call getSwitchValue i write DisplayResultActivit.class (my 2nd activity) and it doesn't get it as a context

Comment: it will return boolean value use it like this:-  boolean switchValue = getSwitchValue(DisplayResultActivit.class);

Comment: ok, now it works, thank you very much, the thing was i had to write getSwitchValue(DisplayResultActivit.this, not .class, but thanks bro !